# A variable from controller always returns nil in view/ Unable to open file ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, view, controller

i am trying to access a variable in controller in the view, but it always returns nil. And this happens with all the variables i tried. Controller code:

```
@hahaha = '20'
puts @hahaha.inspect
```

This returns 20 in controller. Now when i call it at the view:

```
= @hahaha.inspect
```

It returns nil.. I would be very happy if someone has an idea..
Another thing - when i call File.open(file) in the conroller i always get the following error:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen the_file
```

And i think i am having the file to be searched in a wrong directory. But what is the default directory where i should put it? I searched everywhere..

This is the controller code (i am testing various stuff, so i know it is a bit of a mess.. xD)

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    def create
        begin
        @post = Post.new(params[:post])
        rescue Exception => e
            if e.message == 'too large'
                redirect_to news_path(err: 'file')
            else
                raise e
            end
        end
    end

    def fileSave    
        @code.save
        @code.store!(params[:code])
    end

    def update_db
        #client = Client.find_by(id: 2)
        #client.destroy
    end

    def ip
        @user_ip = request.remote_ip()
    end

    def ha
        @haha = 'opa'
    end

    def renderSlim
        contents ='article
    | Glad you tried this app, hope you enjoyed the ride.
    br
        | If you did, you can hit the approval button below.

#enjoy-div
    button
        div
        span'

        @he = Slim::Template.new {contents}
        @he.render
    end

end

class Env
  attr_accessor :name
end


env = Env.new
env.name = "test this layout"

contents = '
article
    | Glad you tried this app, hope you enjoyed the ride.
    br
        | If you did, you can hit the approval button below.

#enjoy-div
    button
        div
        span'

layout = '
html
    body'

# Create new template object with the layout
l = Slim::Template.new { layout }

# Render the contents passing in the environment: env
# so that it can resolve: = name
c = Slim::Template.new { contents }
puts l.render
@hahaha = '20'
puts @hahaha.inspect
File.open('_enjoy.html.slim')
```

Thanks in advice. {:

Comment: You should put this in two separate questions.

Comment: In which action are you setting the variable, also share the Controller? And in which view are you accessing it. Please share more code.

Comment: Yes i should put this in two separate questions but as you see, i guessed that there will not be many answers so... 
Kirti - i am setting the variable outside any class, so in the 'nothingness'. I am accessing it in the Welcome View, and this is the Welcome controller. I do not think the other code from the controller is necessary, but i will update the answer with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all controller variables are usable in a view.

When you call a Controller action, after running filters and callbacks, it will run all the code inside that action and then it will try to render something. By default Rails will look for a view that matches your action name inside the controllers folder. Once inside that view, it will not come back to the controller untill another action is summoned

That view will have access to any variables instantiated in that action, and that action only.

---

So basically you need to set the `@hahaha` variable inside an action that will render the desired view

Example:

Controller.rb

```
    class Controller < ApplicationController

      def action
        @defined_inside_action = "bar"
      end

      def some_method
        @defined_inside_some_method = "foo"
      end

    end
```

Action.html.erb

```
    <%= @defined_inside_action %> #=> bar

    <%= @defined_inside_some_method %> #=> nil
```

Comment: Well i made a function:
`def initializer`  
` @hahaha = '20'`   
` puts @hahaha.inspect`  
`end`  

I tried to put it in the WelcomeController class and outside. Still no results

Comment: @user1945458 In wich view are you trying to access that variable?

Comment: what do you mean by 'which'?

Comment: @user1945458 As you can see in my answer update, every variable defined inside an #action will be usable in a view with the same name. If defined any where else it will be always nil

Comment: @user1945458 Usually it is created one view for each action. maybe if you share the rest of your code I'll be able to help more

Comment: Awh... so the view should be in the name of a method.. I get it, thank you a lot... Can you tell me something about where is the default location where a method from the controller is searching for a file? I mean, is it in the same folder, or public, i tried many things and i can not figure it out, or maybe i have to do some routing?

Comment: @user1945458 Actually an action is different than a method, but you'are startign to getting it

Comment: @user1945458 I guess you could use the entire path as a string. That way you could be sure it is searching in the right place

Comment: Yes but the main thing is, what is the current directory i am starting the path from? Obviously it is not the folder of the controller nor the folder where is the view.

Comment: Hmm, i tried to use the full path (down to the linux root) and it worked, but that would be not useful if i upload it to the server, as i will not have the same file system there. What can i do in that case?